# Command end with a Errno: :EEXIST Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, git, backup

So I am trying to do a backup of git from source with this script: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md ( and the command: sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production) 
It works in the beginning but it stops while dumping the repositories.
What do I have to fix?

```
Dumping repositories ...
rake aborted!                                                                                                                                                                                 
Errno::EEXIST: File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/git/gitlab/tmp/backups/repositories                                                                                                          
/home/git/gitlab/lib/backup/repository.rb:136:in `prepare'                                                                                                                                    
/home/git/gitlab/lib/backup/repository.rb:8:in `dump'                                                                                                                                         
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:69:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'                                                                                                    
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'                                                                                                    
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:backup:repo:create                                                                                                                                                       
(See full trace by running task with --trace)                                                                                                                                                 
root@gitlab-test gitlab/public#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is very clear! Looks like the directory already exists!

Remove it or move it to a temp location.

To move it

```
mv /home/git/gitlab/tmp/backups/repositories /home/git/gitlab/tmp/backups/repositories.old
```